# How to handle checkbox group in Angular 2 RC5?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form where I'd like the user to edit which magazine subscriptions he'd like to receive. The code is as follows:

Component:

```ts
export class OrderFormComponent {

    subscriptions = [
        {id: 'weekly', display: 'Weekly newsletter'},
        {id: 'monthly', display: 'Monthly newsletter'},
        {id: 'quarterly', display: 'Quarterly newsletter'},
    ];

    mySubs = [
        this.subscriptions[1]
    ]

    order = new FormGroup({
        subs: new FormArray(this.mySubs.map(sub => new FormControl(sub)), Validations.required) //Lost at this part
    });
}
```

Template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="order">

<div formArrayName="subs">
    <label>Sign me up for newsletters</label>
    <p *ngFor="let s of subscriptions; let i=index">
        <input type="checkbox"  [value]="s.id" [formControlName]="i" /> {{ s.display }}
    </p>        
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="agree" /> I agree to the terms and conditions.
</div>

{{ order.value | json }}
```

When I run the app, three checkboxes are displayed but only one is checked (the wrong one at that). The one that's checked has a label while the others don't.

[image: component output]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured it out.

In my component I have:

```
// The order retrieved from the server
subscription = {
    schedules: [{id: 'weekly', display: 'Weekly update'}],
}

//The FormGroup element
this.subscriptionForm = new FormGroup({
        //Here I fill up a FormArray with some FormControls initialized to the
        //currently selected schedules
        schedules: new FormArray(this.subscription.schedules.map(schedule => new FormControl(schedule)), Validators.minLength(1))
    });
```

In the view I have:

```
 <div>
    <label>Frequency</label>
    <p *ngFor="let schedule of viewData.schedules">
        <input type="checkbox" 
                [checked]="subscription.schedules.includes(schedule)" 
                (change)="changeSchedules(schedule)"> {{ schedule.display }}
    </p>
 </div>
```

And here is the `changeSchedules()` method in the class:

```
changeSchedules(schedule: any) {
    var currentScheduleControls: FormArray = this.subscriptionForm.get('schedules') as FormArray;
    var index = currentScheduleControls.value.indexOf(schedule);
    if(index > -1) currentScheduleControls.removeAt(index) //If the user currently uses this schedule, remove it.
    else currentScheduleControls.push(new FormControl(schedule)); //Otherwise add this schedule.
}
```

Works like a charm! Form validates as expected, with no extra method needed to retrieve/consolidate the subscription array before form submission.

Comment: How does `[checked]="subscription.schedules.includes(schedule)"` work since `subscription.schedules` never get modified?

Comment: I honestly can't remember how everything else was wired up to have it working. I've since moved on from Angular. Sorry :/

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. It allow me to avoid creating custom component for similar task

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in instantiating the `FormControl`. Instead of making a new instance of `FormControl` for all options, you only made one (by iterating through your `mySub`). Change your code to be something like this (not tested):

```ts
order = new FormGroup({
  // creating an array of form control with default values
  subs: new FormArray(this.subscriptions.map(sub => new FormControl(this.isSelectedSub(sub))), Validations.required)
});


//...
isSelectedSub(sub): boolean {
  return this.mySubs.indexOf(sub) >= 0;
}
```

And you probably need a function to consolidate the checkboxes to an array of selected magazine subscriptions before sending out.